# Apt-get failing in bash script?

Tags: shell-script, apt

I have several machines (running Ubuntu LTS 12.4 64-bit) which need to be configured in the same way, so I created a shell script which will run automatically the first time the machine boots. It works for the most part, but any call to apt-get fails. As an example, here are two commands I want to execute.

```
debconf-set-selections ./files/ldap.preseed
apt-get -y install ldap-auth-client
```

Here is the result if I type those lines directly:

```
root@spare:/tmp/scripts# debconf-set-selections ./files/ldap.preseed
root@spare:/tmp/scripts# apt-get -y install ldap-auth-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be installed:
  ldap-auth-config libnss-ldap libpam-ldap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ldap-auth-client ldap-auth-config libnss-ldap libpam-ldap
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 67 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/200 kB of archives.
After this operation, 877 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages...
[and so on...]
```

But if I execute a shell script containing only those lines, this happens:

```
root@spare:/tmp/scripts# ./ldap.cr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ldap-auth-client
```

The same thing occurs when I run the script using sudo, or chown it to root first. What is the difference, to the program, if it is being called directly or through a shell script? And is it possible to convince it otherwise?

EDIT: More information:

```
root@spare:/tmp/scripts# apt-cache policy ldap-auth-client
ldap-auth-client:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.3
  Version table:
    0.5.3.0
       500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Show the contents of the script, otherwise we may not know.

Comment: It's the two commands given at the top: debconf-set-selections followed by apt-get.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only content of the script? `cat ldap.cr`? And are both on the same system? `apt-cache policy ldap-auth-client`

Comment: There was an echo at the beginning and an echo at the end, but I commented them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the script through dos2unix before executing it caused it to work properly. I'm guessing that apt-get was reading the extra \r at the end of the line as part of the package name, and thus looking for ldap-auth-client\r (which doesn't exist) instead of ldap-auth-client (which does).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command

```
apt-get update
```

before executing *apt-get install* command

Also make sure that urls in */etc/apt/sources.list* are available.